# DjangoREST/React - Why is my frontend/backend token authentication system inconsistent?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, axios, bearer-token

Every API call sent to my API has a header with a Bearer token auth, this is verified when I look through my browsers network panel.

The authentication system works, however, whenever I spin up my dev server and try to carry on from my previously logged-in session, my system blocks every request as a 401 Unauthorized with: `"Invalid token header. No credentials provided."`  as a response. Which is false because I'm sending over a header with the access token?

I can only get it working if I logout and log back in as a user.

Here is my axios instance that I used to make calls to my API.

```
import axios from 'axios';

const baseURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/';

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: baseURL,
    timeout: 9000,
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('access_token'),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        accept: 'application/json',},
});



axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
        return response;
    },
    async function (error) {
        const originalRequest = error.config;

        if (typeof error.response === 'undefined') {
            alert(
                'A server/network error occurred. ' +
                    'Looks like CORS might be the problem. ' +
                    'Sorry about this - we will get it fixed shortly.'
            );
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }

        if (
            error.response.status === 401 &&
            originalRequest.url === baseURL + 'auth/token/'
        ) {
            window.location.href = '/login/';
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }

        if (
            error.response.data.code === 'Invalid token header. No credentials provided.' &&
            error.response.status === 401 &&
            error.response.statusText === 'Unauthorized'
        ) {
            const refreshToken = localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');

            if (refreshToken) {
                const tokenParts = JSON.parse(atob(refreshToken.split('.')[1]));

                // exp date in token is expressed in seconds, while now() returns milliseconds:
                const now = Math.ceil(Date.now() / 1000);
                console.log(tokenParts.exp);

                if (tokenParts.exp > now) {
                    return axiosInstance
                        .post('auth/token/', {
                            refresh: refreshToken,
                        })
                        .then((response) => {
                            localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.data.access);
                            localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', response.data.refresh);

                            axiosInstance.defaults.headers['Authorization'] =
                                'Bearer ' + response.data.access;
                            originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] =
                                'Bearer ' + response.data.access;

                            return axiosInstance(originalRequest);
                        })
                        .catch((err) => {
                            console.log(err);
                        });
                } else {
                    console.log('Refresh token is expired', tokenParts.exp, now);
                    window.location.href = '/login/';
                }
            } else {
                console.log('Refresh token not available.');
                window.location.href = '/login/';
            }
        }

        // specific error handling done elsewhere
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
);

export default axiosInstance;
```

Here is my django auth settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'oauth2_provider.contrib.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',  # django-oauth-toolkit >= 1.0.0
        'drf_social_oauth2.authentication.SocialAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication'
    )
}
```

Is this standard development server behavior? The fact that after every server spin-up stored user sessions need to be "reset"?

Here is what's causing me the confusion, why am I getting an invalid no token message as a response, when the request clearly has a token authentication (this only happens during server boot up).
[image]

Is there something I can fix through Django or React? Let me know if you need more info or code from my side.

Comment: I believe the access token is wrong because you didn't use the refresh token to obtain a new access token. How do you refresh your token ?

Comment: Oh I see that makes sense, in that case my axios code that I posted is not doing its job well, because that is how I would be refreshing the access token.